# Simulate pressing Tab key in Rspec Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, keyboard-events

I'm trying to write tests for managing focus in a dialog modal. How to simulate pressing the keyboard `Tab` key in Rspec Capybara?

Comment: It depends on what driver you're using. For example on Rack::Test (the default driver) there is no way to simulate keypresses as its not actually a real browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `send_keys` method, eg:

```rb
body = find('body')
body.send_keys(:tab)
body.send_keys([:shift, :tab])
```

Out of [all the capybara docs pages](https://rdoc.info/search/github/jnicklas/capybara/master?q=send_keys) for `send_keys`, the [Capybara::Node::Element class](https://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#send_keys-instance_method) has the best write up.

Comment: Note: with recent Capybara you can also call `send_keys` directly on the session and it should get sent to the currently active element `page.send_keys(:tab)` rather than having to find the body first